# Cannot get an image handle from a bitmap within the resources when using "LoadImageA()" and cannot understand why

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to load an image resource using the `LoadImageA()` function, yet it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Here's a bit of my code :

```
bool isRessource = IS_INTRESOURCE(107);

// Load the resource to the HGLOBAL.
HGLOBAL imageResDataHandle = LoadImageA(
    NULL,
    MAKEINTRESOURCEA(107),
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    0,
    0,
    LR_SHARED
    );
HRESULT hr = (imageResDataHandle ? S_OK : E_FAIL);
```

The image I want to load is a bitmap saved in the resources, and represented as such within `resources.h`:

```
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     107
```

When I execute the code, `isRessource` is equal to `true`, yet `hr` is equal to `E_FAIL`.

Any idea as to why this is happening? I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I made the image using Gimp.

Comment: Using `IS_INTRESOURCE()` the way you are is useless, it will always return `true`. So just get rid of it. As for `LoadImage()`, when it returns NULL, you can use `GetLastError()` to find out why. But offhand, one thing I notice is that your ID says `PNG`, but you are loading the resource as `IMAGE_BITMAP`.  What is the actual type for your resource in your `.rc` file ? Is it `BITMAP`, or something else?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was indeed using PNG at the time I posted the post. I changed it back to a bitmap (and changed the values, which I am updating on the original post), without success.

Comment: [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea): *"`hInst`: To load an OEM image, set this parameter to **NULL**."* - You aren't loading an OEM image, so you need to set the value to the appropriate module handle that contains the resource.

Comment: I have found that 32 bit bitmaps generated by GIMP will not load in Windows, FWIW.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yeah, I did have troubles with that at first. It is currently a 16bit 5R 6G 5B image. Well, maybe gimp images doesn't load at all, since I always get an error message while trying to access it. But it still appears within visual studio's image editor.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh, I thought that setting 'hInst' to NULL allowed the function to use the current executable file of the app to get it's module handle... Then I have no clue as to how to do it. I'll start searching around it.

Comment: Pass `GetModuleHandle (NULL)` instead, to load a resource from your .exe

Comment: @PaulSanders I did so, but `hr` is still equals to `E_FAIL`

Comment: And what does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: @PaulSanders It gave "0x01381810". But I found what made the code fail : it was indeed because the image was from Gimp. I guess it doesn't matter on the format of bitmap, as I tried many other format, be it 32bit, 16bit or 24 bit.

Comment: @MrAszter Are you sure `GetLastError()` is returning `0x01381810`? Are you calling `GetLastError()` *immediately* after `LoadImage()` fails, with no other function calls in between? `0x01381810` is not a standard Win32 error code, or a valid Microsoft-defined `HRESULT`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I am sure of it. It is placed right after it.

Comment: @MrAszter are you looking at the error code using a debugger, or a log file?  Maybe you are looking at it BEFORE it is assigned, or maybe you are not logging it correctly. Hard to say since you haven't shown that code yet. But that is definately not an error code that `LoadImage()` should be reporting.

Comment: Using the earlier code, I assigned a `DWORD` to `GetLastError()` right after the `HGLOBAL imageResDataHandle = LoadImageA();` and before the `HRESULT hr = (imageResDataHandle ? S_OK : E_FAIL);`. I then placed the 'stop point' of the debugger at the line of the `HRESULT` (so that it just finished executing `GetLastError()`), then checked my `DWORD` from the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the same image with the same format on another application (I used "Krita") and importing it again, the image finally loads with the same code (I only changed the reference to the resource). I guess that all types of bitmaps made from Gimp won't work in Visual Studio (I tried most formats of bitmaps from Gimp).

Answer (score 0):

The first link searched with **LoadImage gimp** as a keyword is enough to answer this question.

This is some useful information:

> The bitmap exported by GIMP has a broken header. Specifically, the
>   code seems to not write the RGBA masks, which AFAIK are not optional
>   in a BITMAPV5HEADER. This misaligns and changes the size of the entire
>   extended header, incidentally making it look like a BITMAPV4HEADER,
>   which explains why most programs will still open it fine. Without
>   having done any testing, I'd guess LoadImage() is more picky about the
>   values in this extended header; returning NULL is how it indicates
>   failure.

By the way, when you import a bitmap, the system does not remind you that the format of the image is unknown?

Like:

[image]

After testing, use `LoadImage` to load such an image will return NULL, and `GetLastError` will also return 0.

Comment: @MrAszter hi, Is the answer useful to you?